# ASP.Net website installer references

Tags: asp.net, installation, windows-installer, dependencies, vs-web-site-project

Are all the dll's in my Website - Property Pages - References tab copied into an .msi istaller by default for a Website project type?  The references don't seem to have any options as they would in a web app or desktop app project type (such as Copy Local, etc).  My installer includes the Content Files from my website project, and any class libraries I have referenced as projects in my solution are all showing up in the Output list.  But, any system or 3rd party dll's that I have manually added as references do not show up in this list.  Will they be compiled into the installer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Web Setup deployment project. That will check dependencies and you can choose to add them to the .MSI installer.

**edit** This is on a MVC project by the way. I must say i'm not sure if that's the case with Website projects, I often deployed those using XCopy